# What is the purpose of sorting a linked list?

Tags: list, data-structures, linked-list

I am wondering what is the purpose of sorting a linked list. Because if you need to find an element in an unsorted linked list and a sorted linked list, you have to do O(n).
Please forgive if my question is stupid

Comment: None. The list should be maintained in a sorted manner if that's the desired usage. Sorting a linked list is one of the most inefficient operations known to computer science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of sorting isn't always to search in logarithmic time. There are lots of other applications of sorted data obviously.

Suppose, you have to de-duplicate(remove the duplicate elements) from a large linked list and you don't have enough space to load the list items into hashtable as the list is very big. In this case, you can sort the list and remove consecutive elements if they are same and thus de-duplicate the list.

If you want to insert an element into it's appropriate position in a sorted container, sorted linked list is very handy which will guarantee linear time and constant space complexity. But for array, you need to use a temporary array and move all the elements afterwards one by one. Infact [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#LRU) cache is a doubly-linked list under the hood and keep sorted based on the recent hit on items. Newly used item and old item which is recently being accessed again, are inserted in front to keep the already sorted list sorted. If an array like structure would be used here, LRU cache can't offer of constant complexity

This is just some classic applications. You can find a lot of other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Let us think a linked list is used to implement a priority queue. We can add elements of different priorities at random, but we want to process the elements of the queue according to priority, it would be useful to maintain a sorted linked list so that the top priority items appear at the beginning, and removing them from the queue is an easy operation. This not exactly sorting the list, but as and when an item is inserted, it would be placed in it's correct position based on the priority. This is similar to insertion sort of an array.